# Matlab: Add additional info to the data cursor for multiple data sets

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to add additional data to the cursor in a plot similar to [1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68079-how-to-add-additional-info-to-the-data-cursor) however, I have multiple data sets. How can I have the data cursor pull from two data sets.

```
function test
    x1 = 1:10;
    x2 = 1:0.5:10;

    y1 = cos(x1);
    y2 = sin(x2);

    z1 = rand(size(x1));
    z2 = rand(size(x2));

    fig = figure;
    plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
    datacursormode on

    set(dcm_obj,'updatefcn',{@myupdatefcn, {z1, z2}})
end

function txt = myupdatefcn(x,event_obj,t)
    % Customizes text of data tips
    pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
    I = get(event_obj, 'DataIndex');
    txt = {['V: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
           ['j: ',num2str(pos(2))],...
           ['z: ',num2str(t(I))]};
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [Creating Multiple Data tips](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html#f4-50334)  or maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19877-makedatatip/content//makedatatip.m) File Exchange submission ?

Comment: The file exchange script doesn't work and the Matlab doc doesn't address my situation.